# How to override rendering methods of marked compiler under docpad-plugin-marked?

Tags: markdown, docpad

I would like to extend `marked` markdown compiler in the docpad-plugin-marked package and ask for a suggestion how to do this most elegantly.

For example, this is how the documentation of marked says to redefine compiling headers:

```
var marked = require('marked');
var renderer = new marked.Renderer();

renderer.heading = function (text, level) {
  var escapedText = text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w]+/g, '-');

  return '<h' + level + '><a name="' +
                escapedText +
                 '" class="anchor" href="#' +
                 escapedText +
                 '"><span class="header-link"></span></a>' +
                  text + '</h' + level + '>';
},

console.log(marked('# heading+', { renderer: renderer }));
```

The expected result:

```
<h1>
  <a name="heading-" class="anchor" href="#heading-">
    <span class="header-link"></span>
  </a>
  heading+
</h1>
```

But docpad-plugin-marked has its own instance of marked so I suppose I need to inject there rather than creating my own. Its documentation does not explain this case https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-marked

Does anyone know how to do with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this right now because the plugin does not accept a custom renderer 
https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-marked/blob/master/src/marked.plugin.coffee#L26

You have to modify the plugin to accept an option that lets you make a custom renderer.

**Warning** Pseudo code:

```
 if (config.markedRenderer) {
 // make a new renderer
   renderer = new marked.Renderer();
   Object.keys(config.markedRenderer).forEach(function(key) {
     return renderer[key] = config.markedRenderer[key];
   });
 }
    // set the new renderer
   return marked(opts.content, { renderer: renderer }, function(err, result) {
        opts.content = result;
        return next(err);
      });
```

And in your config file:

```
    marked: {
  markedRenderer: {
    heading: function (text, level) {
      var escapedText = text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w]+/g, '-');

      return '<h' + level + '><a name="' +
        escapedText +
        '" class="anchor" href="#' +
        escapedText +
        '"><span class="header-link"></span></a>' +
        text + '</h' + level + '>';
    }
  }
},
```

If you make this work properly it would make a great pull requests for this plugin!

**Update**: I actually needed this functionality, so you can see my fork here:  https://github.com/vladikoff/docpad-plugin-marked/commit/39cc54a0856c5ee0bc784920a6156acf1e1e5568#diff-c25561cb097f02c31ba4fa2cf5dce74eR34

```
plugins: {
marked: {
  markedRenderer: {
    heading: function (text, level) {
      var escapedText = text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w]+/g, '-');

      return '<h' + level + '>' +
        text + ' <a name="' +
        escapedText +
        '" class="anchor" href="#' +
        escapedText +
        '"><span class="header-link"># </span></a></h' + level + '>';
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used to use regexps in events.renderDocument. But your solution looks much more elegant and extendable.

Comment: Also, will you PR your fork into the original plugin source? I think this will be useful for many case, not only headers :-)